# When someone become non observant

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, non-religious

A young man, brought up in a religious home, Yeshiva day and high schools, 2 years in Yeshiva in Israel, decides to work on Shabbos, not observe Kashrut etc. 
Is there one book you would recommend for him to read? This is in addition to finding someone he can learn with. He is willing to learning the issues he has.

Comment: For future reference, you can edit a post to revise your question without having to ask a new question. This can be done by clicking on the "edit" link right below the tags that are right below the question.

Comment: For what purpose are we recommending books for the person? In other words, what is the person hoping to get out of our book recommendations?

Comment: There is a book called "Off the Derech". I think I asked about this book on this site, actually. I have to hunt for it. 2 points - 1) The book may be geared more for you to understand the situation and help him, rather than for him to read. 2) I read it, and it did have some interesting points. While it didn't overly impress me, it may work for you. I just found my question - see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85156/5275

Comment: The person in question learned for two years in yeshiva. Don't you think he's already familiar with anything presented in some book? I think finding a competent rabbi or tackling it yourself would be a much better option for kiruv in this case.

Comment: @ezra for better or worse not everyone learns that much over two years, let alone retains it

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't see how it could be for the better.

Comment: @ezra ר' אבהו אמר זה שיפוטה של תורה שאדם למד תורה ושכחה רבנן דתמן בשם ר' יצחק דהכא ורבי טוביה בש"ר יצחק **לטובתו אדם למד תורה ושוכח** שאילו היה אדם למד תורה ולא שכחה היה מתעסק בתורה שתים שלש שנים וחוזר ומתעסק במלאכתו ולא היה משגיח בה לעולם כל ימיו אלא מתוך שאדם למד תורה ושוכחה אינו מזיז ואינו מזיע את עצמו מדברי תורה

Comment: @alex Fascinating. Where is that quote from?

Comment: @JoelK Koheles Rabba Parsha 1.

Comment: depends very much on the person and the reasons.

Comment: this quote is talking about learning Torah and forgetting it. He wants to learn some of the points for instance, why is electricity considered kindling a fire, why is a chicken considered meat, regarding the Oral tradition is where he is stuck on, on the one hand. He doesn't think any of the laws regarding SHabbas are applicable today. WHat does that quote mean? what does 'forgetting Torah' mean? Does it mean the connection to Hashem and the Jewish people or the specifics of the learning?Getting a Rav is a little hard our Shule Rabbi is away. I will try to get someone to learn these areas.

Comment: @Vernanta Citernbau Electricity is not considered kindling fire. I always hear that one but I've never actually heard any source for that opinion. I think people just mix it up with turning on a incandescent and fluorescent lighbulbs (not led). Those are considered lighting a fire (or bishul).This is talking about on shabbos obviously. Also who is "he"? The OTD guy? What he should read really depends on why he's going OTD.

Comment: There seem to be 3 kinds of OTD from my experience. Ones based on bad experiences in Judaism (I call these emotional OTD) , ones based on questions on Judaism that have plenty of answers that they never recieved because of their community,and ones who go off because of really good questions. Which is he?

Comment: I would say all 3. School was a disaster for him mainly High school. He went to a Boys Yeshiva HS which 'tracks' and due to learning problems, mainly bad test taking, he was in the 'lower' track. Some of the teachers did nothing but yell at them. THey were never given the better Rebbeim, which i had hoped for. By better I mean, people who have published books and are very inspiring at least as speakers. Then one by one all his friends left the fold, it took him a little longer. And his questions are he seems to hate the whole thing he finds fault with every thing.  Now he is good in his job

Comment: for the first time in life he is being successful; but they have to work long hours incl. Friday night and SAt. At first Fri night he came whatever time and made Kiddish but now he just stays out late,. Now anyway they have relocated him to another state to expand the company. I dont know what to do to be honest. I have fears of worst case. there was some drug use of MJ but dafka this chevra he moved with is banning any of this or alcohol in the apt. they rented. There was tobbacco use heavy but he's working on that/

Comment: @VernantaCiternbaum (I didn't see your comment to me until now because you didn't write "@Alex".) The quote I posted was not directly related to your question. Ezra in a comment asked how it could be good to forget Torah. In response to that I quoted a Midrash which states that forgetting Torah is a good thing because if we didn't forget Torah then we would just learn everything once and never learn again.

Comment: Ah that is good.